# Setting SwitchTile toggle based on database values flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

We are using SwitchTiles for a settings screen. I am pulling values from the database to set them to on or off accordingly. How is the initial toggle set to true or false? Is it switchValue?

Heres the Code for one.

```
 SettingsTile.switchTile(
            title: 'Check In',
            leading: Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.blue,),
            switchValue: checkIn,
            onToggle: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                checkIn = value;
                insertFeature(widget.user.userId, 'CheckIn', checkIn);
              });
            },
          ),
```

Answer (score -1):

Its SwitchValue, I found it defined in an outside class.